# Unable to push a single row data into Redshift table. Gives assert error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

If I have a sample dataframe having only one row and I have to push its content to a table on `redshift` using `psycopg2` with python. It throws an error as `ASSERT ERROR`. 
But when I try appending the same row to my existing dataframe and push the data which now has two rows it inserts into the table properly without any problem.

```
con = library.prod_db_connect()
cur = con.cursor()
lead_tuple = [tuple(x) for x in temp_table.values]
psycopg2.extras.execute_values(cur, "INSERT INTO "+str(table)+" VALUES s",lead_tuple, page_size=20000)
cur.close()
con.commit()
con.close()
```

Comment: Can you provide move info please to make it replicatable, including table ddl and example data inside the python script showing both the success and the error? please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example